# Dagger2 Cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

So i'm developing an app with mvp pattern and i'm having issues using Dagger2

I have created an interface for my presenter called HelloPresenter.

And then i created an implementation for that interface called HelloPresenterImpl

My HelloPresenter

```
public interface HelloPresenter {

    public void sayHello();

}
```

My HelloPresenterImpl

```
public class HelloPresenterImpl implements HelloPresenter {

    StoryView storyView;

    @Inject
    public HelloPresenterImpl(StoryView storyView) {
        this.storyView = storyView;
    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        Log.d(TAG, "hello there");
    }

}
```

My component

```
@UserScope
@Component(dependencies = NetComponent.class, modules = RetrofitModule.class)
public interface StoryComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
    void inject(HelloPresenter helloPresenter);
}
```

My module

```
@Module
public class HelloModule {

    @Provides
    public HelloPresenter providesHelloPresenter(final HelloPresenterImpl presenter){
        return presenter;
    }

}
```

My BaseApplication

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application {

    private NetComponent mNetComponent;
    private StoryComponent mStoryComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .netModule(new NetModule())
                .build();

        mStoryComponent = DaggerStoryComponent.builder()
                .netComponent(mNetComponent)
                .retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule())
                .storyModule(new StoryModule())
                .build();

    }

    public NetComponent getNetComponent() {
        return mNetComponent;
    }

    public StoryComponent getStoryComponent() {
        return mStoryComponent;
    }
```

Now, when i try to inject it in my MainActivity, it throws an Error saying

> Error:(18, 10) error: com.exampleapp.Hello.presenter.HelloPresenter
>   cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated
>   method. com.exampleapp.Hello.presenter.HelloPresenter is injected at
>   com.exampleapp.Hello.MainActivity.HelloPresenter
>   com.exampleapp.Hello.MainActivity is injected at
>   com.exampleapp.di.components.HelloComponent.inject(activity)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    @Inject
    StoryInterface storyInterface;

    @Inject 
    HelloPresenter helloPresenter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ((BaseApplication) getApplication()).getStoryComponent().inject(this);

        helloPresenter.sayHello();  // This throws an Error

    }
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without seeing the whole project, my guess is Dagger can't figure how to create `HelloPresenterImpl` instance because you don't provide `StoryView`. I think you'll need:

```
@Provides
public StoryView providesStoryView() {
    return new StoryView();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Comment: Thanks. Also `@Binds` can help for abstract methods.